# how to calculate cross entropy in 3d image pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

[See the figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwpB5.png)

left thing is (2, 480, 640) and it's softmax value

right thing is (2, 480, 640) and it's one-hot encoding value

how to get cross entropy loss in all element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same way as with any other image. Use [binary_cross_entropy(left, right)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy). Note that

1. Both have to be of `torch.float32` `dtype` so you may need to first convert `right` using `right.to(torch.float32)`.
2. If your `left` tensor contains logits instead of probabilities it is better to call [binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(left, right)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits) than to call `binary_cross_entropy(torch.sigmoid(left), right)`